# Are any Rishis of Rig Vedic verses Gods also?

Tags: rig-veda, rishi, vedic-gods

X.110 (936) Āprı ̄
Jamadagni Bhārgava or Rāma Jāmadagnya

Rig Veda X 110 has Jamadagni Bhārgava or Rāma Jāmadagnya as the Rishi - who seems to be the same as the Itihasa-Puranic Parashurama, who is a Vishnu Avatara.